# How to get Mandrill message ID using Mail::send() - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-4, mandrill

Is there a way to get a response from Mandrill using the mail function (or any other function) in Laravel 4?

Using the code below the message sends fine but just returns null:

```
$response = Mail::send('emails.test', [], function($message) 
{
    $message->to('test@email.com')->subject('test email');
});

dd($response);
```

I tried using both the smtp driver and Mandrill driver but it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Also had some issues with logging the fetching `_id` from a Mandrill sent event.
Created a workaround for Laravel 5.7;

Create a CustomMailServiceProvider

```
<?php
// app/Providers/CustomMailServiceProvider.php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Misc\Transport\CustomMandrillTransport;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as HttpClient;

class CustomMailServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider {

    public function register(){
        parent::register();

        $this->registerMandrillMailer();
    }
    /**
     * Register the CustomMandrill Swift Transport instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerMandrillMailer()
    {
        if ($this->app['config']['mail.driver'] == 'mandrill') {
            $this->app->singleton('swift.mailer', function ($app) {
                $mandrillConfig = $app['config']->get('services.mandrill', []);
                return new Swift_Mailer(new CustomMandrillTransport( $this->guzzle($mandrillConfig), $mandrillConfig['secret']));
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a fresh Guzzle HTTP client instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return \GuzzleHttp\Client
     */
    protected function guzzle($config)
    {
        return new HttpClient(Arr::add(
            $config['guzzle'] ?? [], 'connect_timeout', 60
        ));
    }
}
```

Create a CustomMandrillTransport

```
<?php
// app/Misc/Transport/CustomMandrillTransport.php

namespace App\Misc\Transport;

use Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage;

class CustomMandrillTransport extends \Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MandrillTransport {

    public function send(Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {
        $this->beforeSendPerformed($message);

        $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-raw.json', [
            'form_params' => [
                'key' => $this->key,
                'to' => $this->getTo($message),
                'raw_message' => $message->toString(),
                'async' => true,
            ],
        ]);

        // Lets replace body by actually something useful -_-
        $message->setBody((string)$response->getBody());

        $this->sendPerformed($message);

        return $this->numberOfRecipients($message);
    }
}
```

Create an email Listener

```
<?php
// app/Listeners/EmailSentListener.php
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent;
use Mail;

class EmailSentListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Events\OrderShipped  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSent $event)
    {
        $mandrillBody = $event->message->getBody(); // [{"email":"xxxxx@gmail.com","status":"queued","_id":"19219cfd3e0e4133aed48214ebb4ed71"}]
    }
}
```

In config/app.php comment original

```
//        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
```

And Add your own:

```
App\Providers\CustomMailServiceProvider::class,
```

And make sure to listen to sent Event

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
        'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EmailSentListener',
        ]
    ];
}
```

Hope this helps more people

Comment: Hey, we used this.....but for some reason in our local environments its not picking up the customer mail service provider and getBody is just returning the html of the email sent. Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you can.  The MandrillTransport::send does not return anything and it does not expose the HttpClient.

Comment: So any idea how you are supposed to get the message ID from Mandrill then?

Comment: 1. Take the MandrillTransport and create your own custom Transport from that so it does what you want.

2. Use Guzzle and do it your self.